# Copy the first x columns from one Table to another empty Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an empty table `InsertTable` that contains `Meta information` and `Data information` (all together 60 columns). I know that Metainformation is written into the first 20 Columns and want copy them into the Table `MetaInfo` that has (as well as Data columns) specific column names and the other 40 Columns into the Table `DataInfo`. The columns within InsertTable do not have any specific name just `V1-V60`. Now I am looking for a way to perform: copy the first x Columns into the first x columns of Table y. Like you would do it in Excel: Select the first 20 columns to open another workbook insert the 20 columns into B1, since the first column is ID.

I have found this code to copy columns

```
INSERT INTO metaTable (Name)
SELECT v1 FROM InsertTable
```

I can create (via a loop in C#) the select statement for each row and combine them but I have problems creating the `Insert Into Statement` since the Column Names are not consecutive but have their specific name.

Could anyone help me here?

This is how the tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [MetaInfo]
(ID int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
Name varchar(max),
Address varchar(max),
...)

CREATE TABLE [InsertTable]
(v1 varchar(max),
v2 varchar(max),
...)
```

Comment: If you could show sample [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) and some [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). for sample data it would provide a great help for us to answer your question.

Comment: I edited my question and added the table generation code. I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: @ruedi and **DML**. Also, complete DDL statements will help `...)` isn't a good description of your table's definition.

Comment: Sorry, I used ...) since I did not want to insert all 60 columns. I am not doing any data manipulation yet. I got the data via SSE and inserted them with Bulk Insert from CSV. Now I have them in the InsertTable and am not able to split them into two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this sort of thing ,

```
INSERT INTO `messages` ( `m_title`, `m_details`)
            SELECT  m_title, m_details from  temp_messages where id =2
```

above query is for mysql but can be written for MSSQL as well

Comment: SQL Server/T-SQL uses brackets (`[]`) for quote identifiers.

Comment: if your are looking for this query it must be converted to T-SQL

Comment: Is there any way not using the specific column names and instead doing it via loop where the column count number (e.g. 20 see question above) is the input parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could build the SQL dynamically:

```
declare 
    @sourceTable varchar(50) = 'InsertTable'
    ,@targetTable varchar(50) = 'metaTable'
    ,@sourceColumns varchar(4000) = ''
    ,@targetColumns varchar(4000) = ''
    ,@sql varchar(max)


Select 
    @sourceColumns += iif(table_name <> @sourceTable, '', iif(len(@sourceColumns) = 0, '', ', ')  + quotename([COLUMN_NAME], '[]'))
    ,@targetColumns += iif(table_name <> @targetTable, '', iif(len(@targetColumns) = 0, '', ', ')  + quotename([COLUMN_NAME], '[]'))

from (
    select 
        object_name(object_id) as table_name
        ,name as column_name
    FROM sys.columns 
    where object_name(object_id) in (@sourceTable, @targetTable)
    AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id, name, 'ordinal') <= 20  -- only get the first 20 columns
    and is_identity = 0     -- exclude identity columns
) cols



select 
    @sql = concat('INSERT INTO ', @targetTable, ' (', @targetColumns, ')', char(10), 
                    'SELECT ', @sourceColumns, ' FROM ', @sourceTable)

print @sql
exec (@sql)
```